# Why is my 'sh' command in a Jenkinsfile not executing sh "git diff requirements.txt > $WORKSPACE/requirements-diff.txt?

Tags: bash, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

As mentioned in the title, I have the following line in a Jenkinsfile:

`sh "git diff requirements.txt > $WORKSPACE/requirements-diff.tx"`

When I print `requirements-diff.tx` during the build, what is printed is the string

```
git diff requirements.txt
```

So `git diff requirements.txt`  is not being executed and is being treated like a string instead.

Any ideas why this could be?

I am expecting the git diff of the requirements.txt file to be written to `requirements-diff.tx`

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes:

```
sh 'git diff requirements.txt > $WORKSPACE/requirements-diff.tx'
```

You can also run the execution with `$()`

```
sh '$(git diff requirements.txt) > $WORKSPACE/requirements-diff.tx'
```

Haven't tested this so it might need adjusting

Comment: Hi, I've tried both but neither seems to be working... really stuck on this one

Comment: Try `echo $(git diff  requirements.txt) > $WORKSPACE/requirements-diff.tx'`